# Store image data type using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I have an SQL Server database with following table.

Table PROMO, column:

- code , varchar(10)
- name , varchar(10)
- image_data, image
- desc , text

How do I insert an image file as a binary into SQL Server using PHP [PDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History)? The image will be stored in column **image_data**.

What type of variable should I pass to the PDO parameter?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query, array(
    ':code'        => $code,
    ':name'        => $name,
    ':image_data'  => $imageData,
    ':desc'        => $desc
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way as you store any other data, text for example.
There is no difference.

Comment: I mean, what type of variable should I pass to the PDO parameter ?